# MongoDB, when saving a new record overwriting the last document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've developed an API using node & express and mongoDB(3.2.9) (mongooseJS) hosted on mLabs.

When using the sandbox box version everything seems to be working fine, but then when I upgrade to using a cluster I'm always finding that I'm overwriting the last entry in the collection.

I'm not sure whether it's my code or something I need to configure on mLabs.

**Connecting to the server:**

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
// Count the CPU's
const cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

// Create workers on each CPU
for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
}

// Listen for dying workers
cluster.on('exit', (worker) => {
    // Replace the dead worker
    console.log('Worker ${worker.id} died');
    cluster.fork();
});

} else {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Worker '+ port +' running');
    });
}
```

**Saving the data**

db.name = productData.name;
        db.imagePath = productData.imagePath;
        db.price = Number(productData.price).toFixed(2);
        db.siteId = productData.siteId;
        db.url = productData.url;

```
    db.save((error, product) => {
        if(error) {
            utils.handleError(res, error, 'Error message');
        } else {
            // Add to price history
            historyData.saveNewHistory(product._id, productData.price);

            if(boardId){
                boardData.addProductToBoard(boardId, product.url, product._id, userId, targetPrice, productData.price, res);
            }

            res.status(201).json({
                'status': 201,
                'message': 'Added product successfully',
                'product' : product
            });


        }

    });
```

I'm not receiving any error messages so confused as to why it maybe overwiting, the id's are unique as generated by MongoDB

I forgot to mention that this APP/API is hosted on AWS Beanstalk if that means anything.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you replace

`// Create workers on each CPU
for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
}`
with

`// Create workers on each CPU
//for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
//}`?

If it does then your application is not thread safe.  Upgrading to a cluster would make your application create more workers, and if they don't work together well, it could cause them to overwrite each other's data.  Commenting out the for loop causes the process to only make one worker.  If it doesn't work, then I can't help you.

Comment: Afraid that didn't work. I even went down too `app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Worker '+ port +' running');
    });` and still no joy